# Get parent id from child id SQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have data in table, and want get top of ID (parent id from child ID).

```
id (primary_key)        item_id             secondary_item_id
464                     449                 449
465                     449                 464
467                     449                 465
```

From this table i want get id `'464'` from id `'467'`. I try:

```
$parent_id = $wpdb->get_var( "
    SELECT id
    FROM {$bp->activity->table_name}
    WHERE id = 467
" );
```

But return `465`, i want `464`. And i want use just one query., not multiple query.
Please help.

Comment: what is `bp->activity->table_name` ? Try to add it in text, instead of `bp->activity->table_name`. You need to debug this.

Comment: Okay, i edited question., `bp->activity->table_name` jus table name.

Comment: So, you want secondary_item_id from id?

Comment: @Ronnie Oosting, no. i want only primary id. and get result from primary id to.

Comment: Can you try to do this?: Select *, and `var_dump($parent_id);` ? I want to know which result you get.

Comment: @Ronnie Oosting, ops, sory, i change `get_row` to `get_var`, so now return only the value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159647/discussion-between-ronnie-oosting-and-opsional).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$reply = 467; 
for ($x = 1; $x <= 2; $x++) { 
$reply = $wpdb->get_var( " 
SELECT secondary_item_id 
FROM {$bp->activity->table_name} 
WHERE id = $reply 
" ); 
}
```

Change it to this like we discussed in the Chat. You used the wrong `SELECT`.

Documentation of wordpress functions: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/

Perhaps you might change the for loop and use another function which wordpress provides. I've not used wordpress before, so I can not tell you which one should be used. If you (or anyone else) might know it, I can change this answer.

Answer (score 1):

**use ORDER BY `id` DESC  in mysql query**

```
<?php
$parent_id = $wpdb->get_row( "
    SELECT ID
    FROM {$bp->activity->table_name}
    WHERE id = 467 ORDER BY `id` DESC 
" );
?>
```

Comment: That's still only going to get you 467. Look at @ronnieoostings comment above.

Comment: Okay, i edited question `But return 465, i want 464`

Comment: then you can use WHERE id = 467 ORDER BY `id` ASC